# Are compact simple groups homotopically non-abelian?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups

> Take a compact connected simple centreless Lie group $G$.
>   Can the *commutator map* $G\times G\to G$ sending $(x,y)$ to $[x,y]$ be homotopic to a constant map?

I am interested mostly in the case, where $G={\rm PSU}(n)$.

---

As far as I understand, the commutator map is homologically trivial (right?).

There is a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45483/word-maps-on-compact-lie-groups).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is the main theorem in

Araki, S.; James, I. M.; Thomas, E., *"Homotopy-abelian Lie groups"*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 1960.

> **Theorem:** A compact connected Lie group is homotopy-abelian only if it is abelian.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1960-66-04/S0002-9904-1960-10487-9/S0002-9904-1960-10487-9.pdf